# Install python 2.7 on cygwin

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin

How to install Python 2.7 on new cygwin versions (as of 2023)?

Packages for python 2 seem not to be available. Only Python 3 is available.

There are several packages `python2-###` with dependencies to `python2` but no `python2` package.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2023-July/011186.html

Comment: Unless you have very specific requirements which force your hand, you should stay away from Python 2. The currently recommended and supported version of the language is Python 3.

Comment: @tripleee You're absolutely right. We are since long on Python 3. But we have also lots of scripts running on Python 2 that we cannot yet afford to refactor.

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html to support the conversion. Cygwin `python39-devel` package contains `/usr/bin/2to3-3.9`

Comment: You could install a native windows version for Python 2.7 and write some scripts or function as a frontend to it, which does the necessary conversion of the command line arguments (for instance converting a Cygwin path to a Windows path).